# Define a function called articleStats() that takes a string parameter named fileName

Tags: python, function, parameters

> Define a function called articleStats() that takes a string parameter
>   named fileName representing the name of a file. The file contains
>   lower case words separated by spaces. The function returns the total
>   number of all articles. An article is one of the following words: a,
>   the, an.

I know this is a pretty simple question but I'm just really confused on
what it is that I am doing wrong.
This is what I have so far, but I know it's wrong

```
def articleStats(filename):

filename.split()
for word in filename:
        if 'a' or 'the' or 'an' in word:
            print(len(filename))

articleStats('an apple a day keeps the doctor away')
```

Comment: How do you know it's wrong?  You wouldn't go to the doctor and ask for a diagnosis after only saying "I know I'm sick".

Comment: possible duplicate of [if x or y or z == blah](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/if-x-or-y-or-z-blah)

Comment: Because it keeps printing http://gyazo.com/634514dfa357377f496b45baea751fd8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `if 'a' or 'the' or 'an' in word:`. In Python string literals are evaluated as `True` so your condition is seen as: `if True or True or 'an' in word`

Change this to `if 'a' in word or 'the' in word or 'an' in word`

For a better understanding of what is happening, run the following code to see how Python might treat other conditions.

```
tests = [[], ['not empty list'], {}, {'not':'empty dict'}, 0, 1, '', 'not empty string']
for test in tests:
    print test, bool(test)
```